# Scalaz: Bypass IO pipeline?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I am not sure how to do that, what I am trying to do is:

```
 output1 <- step1(...)
 output2 <- step2(....)
 ....
```

What I am trying to do is for a specific `output1`, I would like to not execute `step2` and just go through it. Is there a built-in function part of `scalaz.zio.IO`?

I couldn't find anything beside nested `flatMap` :

```
 step1(...).flatMap {
      case ... => step2(....)
      case ... => step3(...)
 }
```

But that gets ugly when `step2` is also yielding a condition, etc...

I could also use the `Left` part of `IO` but I am already using it for `Exception` and error tracking.

Would `IO[Error, IO[ByPassCondition, ResultForStep2]]` work? But then I am not able to pass `ResultForStep2` down to `step2` if `ByPassCondition` is set...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scalaz's IO, but does an if-guard work? Something like `output2 <- step2(...) if cond(output1)`.

Comment: It does but it gets messy when I have more than one condition or when I need to bypass several down the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
implicit class JumpIO[A, B](io: IO[A, (B, Boolean)]) {
  def mightJumpNext(next: B => IO[A, B]): IO[A, B] = {
    io.flatMap { case (b, test) =>
      if (test) {
        io.map { case (bb, _) => bb }
      } else {
        io.flatMap { case (bb, _) => next(bb) }
      }
    }
  }

  def mightJumpNextChain(next: B => IO[A, (B, Boolean)]): IO[A, (B, Boolean)] = {
    io.flatMap { case (_, test) =>
      if (test) {
        io.map { case (bb, _) => (bb, false) }
      } else {
        io.flatMap { case (bb, _) => next(bb) }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do :

```
  io
    .mightJumpNext(b=> step2(b))
    .mightJumpNext(b => step3(b))
    ...
```